# how to add numbers in numeric string in perl

Tags: perl

I am facing some problem while adding values in numeric string:

I have string that looks like `02:03:05:07:04:06`. All the numbers have to be <10. Now, I have to take a random number from 1-9  and add that number with last position number of the string (e.g. 3).

I the sum>10, then I have add that number to the number in the second last position.

So far, I have

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my $str='02:03:05:07:04:06';
my @arr=split(/:/,$str);
my @new_arr=pop(@arr);
my $rand_val=int(rand(9));
my $val=$new_arr[0]+$rand_val;
if($val>=10)
{
   I am unable to generate a logic here:(

}
```

Please help me out of this problem.

After adding the number we have to join the string and print it also :)

Comment: is 10 allowed or not?  you say "has to be <10" but also "if sum>10".  if you have to add to the second to last position, you add the same random number?  does the last position remain unchanged in that case?  what happens when the second to last position would also go above the limit?

Comment: Are you implementing a "large integer"?  Do you mena add the number from the first to the second? column, or do you mean "carry the tens digit"?

Comment: Looks more like a mac address, but then why would you limit yourself to 10?

Comment: Let's say your random number is 9. So you add that to 6, which makes 15, which isn't allowed. So you add it to 4, which makes 13, also > 10. Why is that OK? Or do you mean to just add 1 to 4, basically overflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $str = '02:03:05:07:04:06';
my @nums = split /:/, $str;
my $add = int(rand(9)) + 1;
my $overflow = 1;
for (1..@nums) {
   if ($num[-$_] + $add < 10) {
      $num[-$_] += $add;
      $overflow = 0;
      last;
   }
}

die "Overflow" if $overflow;

$str = join ':', map sprintf('%02d', $_), @nums;
```

Comment: I assumed you wanted to keep trying in more than the last two positions. If you really just want to try in the last two positions, use `for (1..2)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I just run this and it works. The caveat is that, the lower the last number of the string is, the smaller the chance the "if ($val>=10)" will be valid

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't solve the problem of your rand_val potentially being 0, but I'll leave that as a task for you to resolve.  This should give you what you're looking for in terms of traversing through the values in the array until the the sum of the random value and current most-last value in the array.

```
1  use strict;
2  my $str='02:03:05:07:04:06';
3  my @arr=split(/:/,$str);
4  my $rand_val=int(rand(9));
5  my $val;
6 
7  foreach my $i (reverse @arr){
8    $val = $i + $rand_val;
9    next if ($val >= 10);
10   print "val: $val, rand_val: $rand_val, value_used: $i\n";
11   last if ($val < 10);
12 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I see a misstake : you do

```
my @new_arr=pop(@arr);
(...)
my $val=$new_arr[0]+$rand_val;
```

but `pop` only returns the last element, not a list.

Comment: would you please suggest me some idea so that i can resolve this issue